# Ruby %w(...) vs %w[...]

Tags: ruby

Is there a difference between `%w(don matt james)` and `%w[don matt james]` in Ruby?

Using the Ruby Console, both of them output an array with each word as an element. I'm curious why there are multiple ways to do this - and how each way is supposed to be used.

Comment: Note: it doesn't have to be words only: `%w[ this is\ power ] #=> ["this", "is power"]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference. Any single non-alpha-numeric character or any "paired" set of characters can be used as delimiters, as covered in http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals (see "The % Notation") and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings

Answer (score 5):

Either option is fine, and produces the same result.  There are even a couple of additional variations on the syntax:

```
%w'don matt james'
%w{don matt james}
```

Comment: Not "a couple" of additional variations; a very large variety of ASCII characters work, e.g. `%w$oh my$` or `%w| yup |` etc. (That's no reason for a downvote, however.)

Comment: Fair enough.  These are just the ones I see in reasonably common use.

Answer (score 4):

With your particular example, the outputs are the same, but there is a difference. The purpose of freedom of delimiters is to allow different characters inside the literal without escaping. If you use certain characters as delimiters, then you cannot use them inside the notation without escaping. Depending on what you might have, you should use different delimiters.

```
["foo()", "bar()"]
%w(foo() bar()) # => error
%w[foo() bar()]

["foo[1]", "bar[5]"]
%w(foo[1] bar[5])
%w[foo[1] bar[5]] # => error
```